# ERROR ORA-00907 Falta el paréntesis derecho

Tags: oracle

**¿Por qué tengo error si mis paréntesis están completos?**

> Script

```
CREATE TABLE asociacion(
idAsoc NUMBER(3),
nombAsoc VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
descAsoc VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT asocPK PRIMARY KEY(idAsoc),
CONSTRAINT asocFK FOREIGN KEY (idProf) REFERENCES profesor,
CONSTRAINT asocUK UNIQUE (idProf) REFERENCES profesor);
```

> Output

```
CONSTRAINT asocUK UNIQUE (idProf) REFERENCES profesor)
                                  *
ERROR en lφnea 7:
ORA-00907: falta el parΘntesis derecho
```

Comment: Porque los constraints UNIQUE no referencian a nadie :) Te dice que esperaba que terminaras ahí y no terminaste :P

Comment: gracias, ya entendí mi error:)